# Why doesn't `Automatic store updates` work on client side store in react application?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am using `react-apollo` to manage client store in my react application so there is no backend graphql server. Everything related to `apollo` is running in the client side. I store all UI state in the cache of `ApolloClient`. And I also define all resolvers in the client side.

Below is the code to new a client instance:

```
new ApolloClient({
    cache,
    resolvers: {
      Mutation: {
        ...cartResolvers,
      },
    },
    typeDefs: [typeDefs]
  });
```

I have read this article https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/features/cache-updates/#automatic-store-updates about automatically update store by using `ID` in apollo graphql mutation and query. But it doesn't seem to work. I have below query and mutation:

```
export const queryCart = gql`
  {
    cart @client {
      items {
        id
        name
        price
        quantity
        image
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const addToBasket = gql`
  mutation addToBasket($sku: ID!) {
    addToBasket(id: $sku)  @client {
      items {
        id
        name
        price
        quantity
        image
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

And I have defined the resolver for that mutation `addToBasket`.

```
const addToBasket = (_parent: any, item: { id: string }, { cache }: ResolverCacheType): CartProps => {
   ...
   return {
      items: [ {id, name, price, quantity, image } ]
   }
}
```

I found that even I return the `id` in the resolver, the cache is not updated and the query is not reactive. I can make it work by manually update the cache data in the resolve by `cache.writeData`.

Answer (score 0):

Your use case is different from the automatic update scenario provided by `react-apollo`: The mutation you run does not update the item itself. Instead, it updates an array that is not keyed in any way for `react-apollo` to track its changes.

To take advantage of the auto update feature, you can change the data structure of the item array from the simple array it is now to an object that looks similar to this:

```
{ _id, [{id, name, price, ...}]}
```

Both the query and the mutation should return this object. Then you have the same setup as the example in [the doc](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/features/cache-updates/#automatic-store-updates). After the mutation runs, the return object has the same `_id` as the local cache, therefore `react-apollo` knows it needs to update the cache data.

Alternatively, you can either manually use `cache.writeData` as you already mentioned or use [`refetchQueries`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/features/cache-updates/#refetchqueries) to update the cart items array.

Comment: Could you please explain more about ` it updates an array that is not keyed in any way`? How can I make the change on the array to make automatic update work?

Comment: @ZhaoYi The way the auto update works is that the `id` (or `_id`) field has to be present in the object you wish to be updated. The basket array does not have it.

Comment: @ZhaoYi You can take advantage of the auto update feature if you assign an id to the basket array. So the data for the items in user's basket will look like this: `{ id, [ { id, name, price ...}]}`. Both the query and the mutation should return this object.